# Версия c# wcf сервиса при создание

Tags: c#, wcf

Почему при создании wcf сервиса на с# на фраемворке 4.7.2 устанавливается версия c#5? И как это можно поменять[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: wcf как по мне - устаревшая технология

Comment: Как вы создаёте этот сервис? Опишите шаги.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Добавить, создать проект, wcf сервис в vs 2019

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса